# box-shadow or border

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после нажатия остается вот такой бордер или это оутлайн или может быть бокс-шедоу, вообщем перепробовал все.. может у кого было ?

```html
<button type="submit" name="#" class="button">Оставьте заявку</button></a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас `<button>` внутри `<a>` — не делайте так, достаточно одного тега. Если это кнопка, которая делает какие-то действия на этой странице, используйте кнопку, а если это кнопка, которая ведёт на другую страницу — используйте ссылку.

Во-вторых, конкретно в этом случае, чтобы убрать эту декорацию, используйте стиль `a[data-toggle="modal"]:focus { outline: none }`.

В-третьих, не забывайте [о доступности](http://prgssr.ru/tag/accessibility). Элементы, на которых возможен фокус, должны как-то подсвечиваться для пользователя — походите по своему сайту с помощью клавиши TAB и сами поймёте зачем это нужно. Так что мой совет — избавьтесь от аутлайна, если он портит ваш дизайн, но добавьте стили для состояния фокуса.

Comment: спасибо, буду стараться

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что вы жмете на ссылку *a*, а не на *button*. Для ссылок у вас установлен  `outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;`. Чтобы переопределить задайте для `a href="#myModal"` - `outline:none;`